# Cannot create thumbnail in ImageMagick: "convert: no decode delegate for this image format"

Tags: imagemagick, mediawiki

I've been at this all day. I'm trying to upload images to a Mediawiki and this is the error I get when ImageMagick tries to create the thumbnail:

```
Error creating thumbnail: convert: no decode delegate for this image format `/tmp/magick-11924QG1rRXzT948I' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/552.
convert: no images defined `/tmp/s3thumb-cripEh' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3127.
```

I setup a debug file for mediawiki and this is what I get in the log:

```
BitmapHandler::doTransform: creating 112x120 thumbnail at /tmp/s3thumb-cripEh using scaler im
BitmapHandler::doTransform: called wfMkdirParents(/tmp)
BitmapHandler::getMagickVersion: Running convert -version
wfShellExec: /bin/bash '/var/www/mediawiki-1.21.2/includes/limit.sh' ''\''/usr/local/bin/convert'\'' -version' 'MW_CPU_LIMIT=180; MW_CGROUP='\'''\''; MW_MEM_LIMIT=202400; MW_FILE_SIZE_LIMIT=102400; MW_WALL_CLOCK_LIMIT=180'
BitmapHandler::transformImageMagick: running ImageMagick: '/usr/local/bin/convert' -quality 80 -background white -define jpeg:size=112x120 ''  -thumbnail '112x120!' -depth 8 -sharpen '0x0.4'  -rotate -0   '/tmp/s3thumb-cripEh' 2>&1
wfShellExec: /bin/bash '/var/www/mediawiki-1.21.2/includes/limit.sh' 'OMP_NUM_THREADS='\''1'\'' '\''/usr/local/bin/convert'\'' -quality 80 -background white -define jpeg:size=112x120 '\'''\''  -thumbnail '\''112x120!'\'' -depth 8 -sharpen '\''0x0.4'\''  -rotate -0   '\''/tmp/s3thumb-cripEh'\'' 2>&1' 'MW_CPU_LIMIT=180; MW_CGROUP='\'''\''; MW_MEM_LIMIT=202400; MW_FILE_SIZE_LIMIT=102400; MW_WALL_CLOCK_LIMIT=180'
[thumbnail] thumbnail failed on ip-10-168-26-167: error 1 "convert: no decode delegate for this image format `/tmp/magick-11924QG1rRXzT948I' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/552.
convert: no images defined `/tmp/s3thumb-cripEh' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3127." from "'/usr/local/bin/convert' -quality 80 -background white -define jpeg:size=112x120 ''  -thumbnail '112x120!' -depth 8 -sharpen '0x0.4'  -rotate -0   '/tmp/s3thumb-cripEh' 2>&1"
LocalS3File::transform thumb:
LocalS3File::transform thumbTempPath: /tmp/s3thumb-cripEh, dest: wiki-images/thumb/1/19/5ovrDaU.jpg/112px-5ovrDaU.jpg
info:1
LocalS3File::transform return thumb: MediaTransformError Object
(
    [htmlMsg] => Error creating thumbnail: convert: no decode delegate for this image format `/tmp/magick-11924QG1rRXzT948I' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/552.<br />
convert: no images defined `/tmp/s3thumb-cripEh' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3127.<br />

    [textMsg] => Error creating thumbnail: convert: no decode delegate for this image format `/tmp/magick-11924QG1rRXzT948I' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/552.<br />
convert: no images defined `/tmp/s3thumb-cripEh' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3127.<br />

    [width] => 112
    [height] => 120
    [url] =>
    [path] =>
    [file] =>
    [page] =>
    [responsiveUrls] => Array
        (
        )

    [storagePath:protected] =>
)
```

Tried from the command line, copy pasted the command from the log (but used a test file):

`convert -quality 80 -background white -define jpeg:size=112x120 ''  -thumbnail '112x120!' -depth 8 -sharpen '0x0.4'  -rotate -0   'logo.jpg`'

but the process hangs. If I run:

```
sudo convert logo.png -quality 80 -background white -define jpeg:size=112x120  -thumbnail '112x120!' -depth 8 -sharpen '0x0.4'  -rotate -0 logo.jpg
```

It works.

If I check DELEGATES, I have:

```
DELEGATES      jng jp2 jpeg png ps tiff xml zlib
```

I tried increasing the default memory on media wiki to

```
$wgMaxShellMemory = 202400;
```

I feel like I've tried anything. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
This is what I've discovered so far:

I'm pretty sure the shell wasn't executing the ImageMagick command because of the escaped backslashes in :

```
wfShellExec: /bin/bash '/var/www/mediawiki-1.21.2/includes/limit.sh' ''\''/usr/local/bin/convert'\'' -version' 'MW_CPU_LIMIT=180; MW_CGROUP='\'''\''; MW_MEM_LIMIT=202400; MW_FILE_SIZE_LIMIT=102400; MW_WALL_CLOCK_LIMIT=180'
```

Those `''\''` are causing the command to not run, and hence the `"no decode"` error. It can't decode, because the file is not there. I've traced `wfShellEec` to `GlobalFunctions.php`. The wfShellExec function is at around line 2778 on my file.

In the `if ( php_uname( 's' ) == 'Linux' )` block there is:

```
escapeshellarg( $cmd )
```

I removed the `escapeshellarg()` function and just left the `$cmd` on its own.

Tried uploading again, the error is gone, the files are created, but now the thumbnail files are 0 bytes.

Any ideas?

Comment: What MW version? I recently get the same on 1.22alpha

Comment: Running mediawiki-1.21.2

Answer (score 0):

In the following, the empty string parameter `''` represents what is supposed to be the input image:

```
convert -quality 80 -background white -define jpeg:size=112x120 '' -thumbnail '112x120!' -depth 8 -sharpen '0x0.4' -rotate -0 'logo.jpg'
```

When you ran `sudo convert logo.png ...` from the command line it worked because you had an input image (`logo.png`), but inside MW the source image parameter was missing. So the problem here is not with `convert`, ImageMagick naturally cannot convert an image that doesn't exist. The problem is that MW fails to supply the source image file name.

If your case is like mine, the empty `''` image source parameter could trace back to permissions in the `images` directory. Make sure this directory and all its subdirectories are  rwx by the server process. Once I opened up everything in this dir to the server, the errors went away and the images and thumbnails appeared perfectly.